# Are images in HTML Mail getting replaced?

Tags: email, image

Is it possible that several mail applications (e.g. Hotmail, Thunderbird, OSx Mail) replace the whole `<img>` tag?

In the generated newsletter i have e.g.:

```
<img style="padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px; outline: none; " class="editor-img" src="/upload/11/2_5.jpg" alt="image" width="165" height="107">
```

and in the received newsletter i got something like:

```
<img src="foo" border="0">
```

Can someone explain me that and how i can prevent this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is absolutely possible. For instance T-Online in Germany exchanges images ending on .php with a dummy image. Many webmailers parse and adapt email code before it is finally rendered in the inbox. Like Gmail tel:-links numbers of which it thinks it's a phone number. In your case, the relative path doesn't make any sense. Try an absolute image path like `src="http://www.YOURDOMAIN/upload/11/2_5.jpg"`.

Comment: The absolute path will be generated. Anyway, thanks. I'll investigate this a bit.